# How to make the Rx callbacks run on the ThreadPool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive, rx.net

Would you expect that the program below prints `False`?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Observable
            .Return(1)
            .ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
            .Do(x => Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread))
            .Wait();
    }
}
```

Output:

```xml
False
```

My undestanding was that the [`ThreadPoolScheduler`](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#ThreadPool) is intended for scheduling work on the `ThreadPool`, but apparently this is not what happening. Its name probably refers to some other thread pool, internal to Rx, and not to the actual [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) class in the `System.Threading` namespace.

I made various attempts to force the callback to run on the `ThreadPool`, but with no success. Some things I've tried:

```
.ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
```

```
.ObserveOn(DefaultScheduler.Instance)
```

```
.ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
```

```
.ObserveOn(new TaskPoolScheduler(Task.Factory))
```

```
.ObserveOn(new TaskPoolScheduler(new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.Default)))
```

```
ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance.DisableOptimizations(); // At the start of the program
```

The last attempt above was after reading [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b56aaa2-aa8e-4f09-a2b0-f9a042efa5a4/observeonthreadpool-uses-newthread?forum=rx) question in Microsoft's forums. No matter what I've tried, the [`Thread.IsThreadPoolThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isthreadpoolthread) property keeps returning `false`.

Am I supposed to wrote my own `IScheduler` implementation to ensure that my code runs on the `ThreadPool`? It sounds like a quite significant undertaking for such a trivial goal.

.NET 5.0.1, System.Reactive 5.0.0, C# 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you shared actually has a solution:

```
var modScheduler = ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance.DisableOptimizations(new[] { typeof(ISchedulerLongRunning) });
Observable
    .Return(1)
    .ObserveOn(modScheduler)
    .Select(_ => Thread.CurrentThread)
    .Subscribe(t => Console.WriteLine(t.IsThreadPoolThread));
```

If you look at the source of [`ThreadPoolScheduler`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Concurrency/ThreadPoolScheduler.cs), you'll see that all the work gets sent to the ThreadPool, except for `ScheduleLongRunning`. If you disable that optimization, then all work will get sent to the ThreadPool.

Comment: Excellent! I didn't realize that the `DisableOptimizations` method has a return value. I expected that it would configure/modify the existing scheduler! So an one-line solution is `.ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance.DisableOptimizations())` 