# IObservable ObserveOn is locking the Thread, is this preventable?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, system.reactive, reactivex

I'm designing a server that diverts client requests to a single thread dedicated to handling data.  I do this to prevent any race conditions or concurrency issues with the data being handled.  Because the server is designed to be reactive, whenever the server receives a request I use Observables to notify the rest of the program of the request.  Now because the server socket is listening and emitting signals from multiple threads I want to ensure that the observables, no matter what thread the server **emits** on, would always be **observed** on the dedicated data handling thread.  I opted to use the `ObserveOn` method and this immediately backfired.  I noticed immediately that upon one observable firing, none of the others were firing.
Not only that, but other actions sent to the dedicated thread weren't firing either.

Essentially, the observable seems to be "claiming" the thread for itself.  The thread is completely blocked by the observable and cannot be used for anything else at all other than that observable's emissions.  I don't want this happening because this thread is dedicated to all data handling operations, and this is stopping me from using the thread for any other observables or future data handling tasks.  So, what are my options here to prevent the observable locking the thread down to itself, or to force observation of observables to my dedicated thread without blocking out other observables.

This example code demonstrates the problem. Here we use a single threaded task scheduler and notice that it operates just fine until the first subject, which has been set to `ObserveOn` the scheduler, emits it's string.  After this happens, no further subject or action fires.  The first subject effectively locked the thread down for itself.

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Within the Tester class we setup a single threaded task scheduler that will be handling all of these methods
        var _t = new Tester();

        string _string = "Hello World";

        //These three will print their string to the console
        _t.PrintDirectlyWithAction(_string);//Succeeds
        _t.PrintDirectlyWithAction(_string);//Succeeds
        _t.PrintDirectlyWithAction(_string);//Succeeds

        //Only subject 1 will emit and print it's string, the other two fail
        _t.PrintThroughSubject1(_string);//Succeeds
        _t.PrintThroughSubject2(_string);//Fails
        _t.PrintThroughSubject3(_string);//Fails

        _t.PrintDirectlyWithAction(_string);//Fails
        _t.PrintDirectlyWithAction(_string);//Fails
        _t.PrintDirectlyWithAction(_string);//Fails

        //We essentially can't do anything with the thread after subject 1 observed on it

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class Tester
    {
        TaskFactory tf;
        TaskPoolScheduler pool;
        int _actionCount = 0;
        Subject<string> s1 = new Subject<string>();
        Subject<string> s2 = new Subject<string>();
        Subject<string> s3 = new Subject<string>();

        public Tester()
        {
            //We're create a task pool that uses a single threaded concurrent task scheduler
            var _scheduler = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair();
            tf = new TaskFactory(_scheduler.ExclusiveScheduler);
            pool = new TaskPoolScheduler(tf);

            //And then we set the subjects to each be observed on the single threaded scheduler
            s1.ObserveOn(pool).Subscribe(_s => Console.WriteLine(
                $"Subject (1) says \"{_s}\" - on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"));
            s2.ObserveOn(pool).Subscribe(_s => Console.WriteLine(
                $"Subject (2) says \"{_s}\" - on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"));
            s3.ObserveOn(pool).Subscribe(_s => Console.WriteLine(
                $"Subject (3) says \"{_s}\" - on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"));
        }

        public void PrintThroughSubject1(string _string)
        {
            s1.OnNext(_string);
        }

        public void PrintThroughSubject2(string _string)
        {
            s2.OnNext(_string);
        }

        public void PrintThroughSubject3(string _string)
        {
            s3.OnNext(_string);
        }

        public void PrintDirectlyWithAction(string _string)
        {
            //This is here to demonstrate that the single threaded task scheduler accepts actions just fine
            //and can handle them in sequence
            tf.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Direct action ({_actionCount++}) says \"{_string}\" - on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            });
        }

    }
}
```

TL;DR: I need to be able to force multiple observables emissions to be observed on a specific thread, but RxNet seems to only be letting a single subject be observed on a thread and nothing else can.  How can I circumvent this to observe multiple observables on the same thread?

Comment: I usually use a background worker which doesn't lock up the main thread.

Comment: It's not the main thread being locked.  It's a secondary thread that I'm feeding the Observables emissions to by using IObservable.ObserveOn().  I think its becoming locked while waiting for the observables next emissions and I'm trying to prevent that, or find a way around it.

Comment: Could you include a minimal example that reproduces the locked-thread behavior?

Comment: Absolutely.  I had it on here while I was writing the post but decided to remove it for brevity's sake.  But, I'll put it back in.

Comment: Your question is still quite obscure IMHO. You should probably include sample output of the program, and explain what part of the output is not expected, and what would be the expected output. My guess is that your question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66314910/how-to-make-the-rx-callbacks-run-on-the-threadpool) question, in which case the problem is that neither the `TaskPoolScheduler` nor the `ThreadPoolScheduler` schedule work on the `ThreadPool`, unless you "de-optimize" them. A bewildering Rx feature, probably implemented after a crazy cocktail party.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to schedule multiple observables to be observed on the same "secondary" thread.  Whats happening right now is that if I "ObserveOn" to the thread, the first observable to emit will lock the thread to only itself and no other observables can fire on it.  I'm trying to find a way for this not to happen.

Comment: @DoctorDep - I don't understand what the code sample you've provided is showing me. Can you please explain it in detail?

Comment: @DoctorDep - Here's a typical run that I get: https://pastebin.com/AcTNm2UG

Comment: @DoctorDep - Sorry, I should have mentioned that I added the `s{n} :: ` to the subscriptions.

Comment: @Enigmativity Hey, sorry for late reply.  Was moving apartments over the weekend and got caught up till today.  What's being displayed is that each subject is locking down a specific thread and it isn't reused by anything else.  In your pastebin notice that s1 runs on thread 28, s2 on thread s9, and s3 on 30.  This is fine and dandy.  But, notice that those thread as never able to be reused by any other activity.  They are locked down.  The threadpool will never use those threads for anything else, not even an inserted Action.  Run the test as many times as you like and see.

Comment: @Enigmativity I need the thread to not be locked down, permanently inaccessible, because I want to have dedicated threads for certain activities.  These dedicated threads may also need to be used for observing Observables to avoid concurrency issues.  What I can't figure out is how to observe on these threads without also locking them down to said observable.

Comment: @DoctorDep - I don't think you're understanding what you're seeing. Rx tries to avoid changing threads. If values are queued up in an observable the current thread is reused. You're not seeing the thread locked to an observable. You're just seeing a subscription trying to process multiple values as efficiently as possible.

Comment: @Enigmativity I've edited my post to try and make my situation a bit more clear.  I feel like I haven't been describing very well my intentions for what I was trying to do, what went wrong, and what I'm hoping to get help to achieve.  Most of the changes are in the first paragraph, and final paragraph before the example code.  Let me know if it is any clearer, and if you can help me come up with a better implementation idea.

Comment: "so the thread is locked down listening to the entire stream until completion" - this is definitely not true. That's not how Rx works.

Comment: @Enigmativity Here, I think my post was dodgy and very unclear.  Also, the example code really didn't demonstrate what it needed to demonstrate; the actual use problem.  So, I rewrote most of the post, and completely changed the code.  Tell me your thoughts, and if my problem is clear now.  If you have any suggestions to a solution to my problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have over complicated it. `EventLoopScheduler` might be what you need.

Try this:

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Within the Tester class we setup a single threaded task scheduler that will be handling all of these methods
        var _t = new Tester();

        string _string = "Hello World";

        //These three will print their string to the console
        _t.PrintDirectlyWithAction(_string);//Succeeds
        _t.PrintDirectlyWithAction(_string);//Succeeds
        _t.PrintDirectlyWithAction(_string);//Succeeds

        //Only subject 1 will emit and print it's string, the other two fail
        _t.PrintThroughSubject1(_string);//Succeeds
        _t.PrintThroughSubject2(_string);//Fails
        _t.PrintThroughSubject3(_string);//Fails

        _t.PrintDirectlyWithAction(_string);//Fails
        _t.PrintDirectlyWithAction(_string);//Fails
        _t.PrintDirectlyWithAction(_string);//Fails

        //We essentially can't do anything with the thread after subject 1 observed on it

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class Tester
    {
        private EventLoopScheduler els = new EventLoopScheduler();
        int _actionCount = 0;
        Subject<string> s1 = new Subject<string>();
        Subject<string> s2 = new Subject<string>();
        Subject<string> s3 = new Subject<string>();

        public Tester()
        {
            //We're create a task pool that uses a single threaded concurrent task scheduler


            //And then we set the subjects to each be observed on the single threaded scheduler
            s1.ObserveOn(els).Subscribe(_s => Console.WriteLine(
                $"Subject (1) says \"{_s}\" - on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"));
            s2.ObserveOn(els).Subscribe(_s => Console.WriteLine(
                $"Subject (2) says \"{_s}\" - on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"));
            s3.ObserveOn(els).Subscribe(_s => Console.WriteLine(
                $"Subject (3) says \"{_s}\" - on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"));
        }

        public void PrintThroughSubject1(string _string)
        {
            s1.OnNext(_string);
        }

        public void PrintThroughSubject2(string _string)
        {
            s2.OnNext(_string);
        }

        public void PrintThroughSubject3(string _string)
        {
            s3.OnNext(_string);
        }

        public void PrintDirectlyWithAction(string _string)
        {
            //This is here to demonstrate that the single threaded task scheduler accepts actions just fine
            //and can handle them in sequence
            els.Schedule(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Direct action ({_actionCount++}) says \"{_string}\" - on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            });
        }

    }
}
```

I get this result:

```
Direct action (0) says "Hello World" - on thread 17
Direct action (1) says "Hello World" - on thread 17
Direct action (2) says "Hello World" - on thread 17
Subject (1) says "Hello World" - on thread 17
Subject (2) says "Hello World" - on thread 17
Subject (3) says "Hello World" - on thread 17
Direct action (3) says "Hello World" - on thread 17
Direct action (4) says "Hello World" - on thread 17
Direct action (5) says "Hello World" - on thread 17
```

Don't forget to `.Dispose()` your `EventLoopScheduler` when you're done.

Comment: I had looked through the concurrency namespace for Reactive several times and somehow completely overlooked this class.  The EventLoopScheduler is exactly the class I needed.  You sir are my hero.  Thank you for your patience with my posts horrible early writeup and for going back and forth with me to figure out my issue.  Godspeed friend.